# Android view set text color

Tags: android, view, textcolor

I am trying to dynamically change the font and background color of my app but when I try to set it just turns gray no matter what color I choose. I have verified the color is correct. any ideas.

mTitleText is a EditText

```
mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note_edit_title);
mTitleText.setTextColor(R.color.defaulttextred);
```

Comment: How do you set the text? are you sure there's no `ColorSpan` in the Text?

Comment: please clarify what you want do?

Comment: Just for the sake of Experimentation, try `mTitleText.setTextColor(Color.RED);`

Comment: Color.RED works? if i use my custom color in the xml it works fine, but using it to set the text dynamically it just turns gray. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
mTitleText.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.defaulttextred));
```

Comment: this works, why does this work and what i was doing not work? Does this doing something in particular that's different? Sorry I am new to android programming

Comment: Its so simple. we cant access string from Strings.xml file using R.String.anystring but to access string we have to write whole code getResources.getString(R.string.anystring). similar case is for color. R.color.colorname return only color id which is specified in R file.it does not return color . for more details see android site